# Is there a way to declare an implicit val inside a for comprehension?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-2.10, scala-2.9, for-comprehension

I have some code with nested calls to flatMap like so:

```
foo.flatMap(implicit f => bar(123).flatMap(b =>
  /* and so on... implicit f is still in scope here.*/
))
```

Normally, one would write that as a for comprehension, which makes the code a lot more readable:

```
for {
  f <- foo
  b <- bar(123)
  /* yet more method calls that need f as an implicit parameter*/
}
```

But I need `f` to be implicit and I don't see a way to do that with for comprehensions. Is there? Of course I could pass f explicitly, but that would mean bye bye pretty DSL. I'd be interested in answers for both Scala 2.9 and 2.10.

Just to be clear, I would like to do something like this, but it won't compile:

```
for {
  implicit f <- foo
  b <- bar(123) //bar takes implicit argument
  /* yet more method calls that need f as an implicit parameter*/
}
```

**EDIT:** Maybe a feature request would be a good idea?

**EDIT2:** This should work with all types that can be used in a for comprehension, so not just with the usual collection types like `List` or `Seq`, but also with `Future`.

Comment: I would go with the feature request...

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot under SI-2823; I looked at it, at the time of this question. There are other issues bearing on this encoding, if you see implicit f<-foo as f0<-foo;implicit f=f0. If you edit the question to specify Futurism as a requisite, I can upvote, too.

Comment: @som-snytt: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "specify Futurism as a requisite". Maybe you can edit the question yourself or suggest an edit?

Comment: Can I edit it? Still an SO newbie.  By Futurism, I was being cute about your old comment on another answer that it must work with futures.

Comment: @som-snytt: If you can't edit it (due to low reputation), you can suggest an edit and I can improve it. I'll edit it and then you can add to that if you feel that's necessary.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there isn't. There is a ticket though: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2823

Comment: 8th year anniversary for this issue, yay

Comment: FYI This is fixed since Scala 3.0

Answer (score 13):

Since version 0.3.0-M1, a [better-monadic-for](https://github.com/oleg-py/better-monadic-for#define-implicits-in-for-comprehensions-or-matches) compiler plugin provides such functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Scala 3 (Dotty) enables [givens](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/givens.html) (implicits) in for-comprehensions, for [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZutNoWQ2QDW0dAG1QaoWwg)

```
Starting dotty REPL...
scala> for {
     |   given Int <- Some(41)
     |   y <- Some(1)
     | } yield summon[Int] + y
val res0: Option[Int] = Some(42)
```

According to [Implicits in for comprehensions/pattern matches SIP tracking #6](https://github.com/scala/slip/issues/6#issuecomment-158483965)

> Martin points out that it Dotty already supports the more ambitious
> version as long as the types are annotated. so e.g. in Dotty this
> compiles: `implicit val (a: Int, b: String) = (3, "foo")`

Comment: `given Int <- Some(41)` now, no name, no `_:` - as i see now

Answer (score 0):

How about this code?

```
// prerequisites
val (a,b) = (List(1,2,3), List(3,4,5,7,9))
def tree(n: Int)(implicit s: Int) = " "*s + "0"*n + (if (s+3 < n) "*" else "")

// actual for
@volatile implicit var s = 0
for (i <- a if ({s = i; true}); j <- b) 
  println(tree(j))

// 000
// 0000
// 00000*
// 0000000*
// 000000000*
//  000
//  0000
//  00000
//  0000000*
//  000000000*
//   000
//   0000
//   00000
//   0000000*
//   000000000*
```

Comment: Apart from being a terrible hack, this also won't work with futures (without making s volatile) or with parallel collections.

Comment: Thank you, added volatile. Do you like a tree?

Comment: +1 because it looks like the Scala Christmas tree from a few seasons back. Don't know if I can find the link now, but I'll try google.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/12024, an easy google. It doesn't actually look like the scala tree, but maybe it will result in a puzzler.

Comment: How cool! Mine was a Christmas Tree of Pisa, falls only on the left side. Product of the last day of vacation, that's why.